# Как использовать OR в условии laravel validate?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

есть форма с select полем «state», значение которого должно быть «draft» или «published». как это сделать? сейчас не работает.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|unique:article_categories' . $category->id,
    'description' => 'required|min:200',
    'state' => 'draft' || 'published'
]);
```

Answer (score 4):

нужно использовать **Rule::in([])**

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|unique:article_categories' . $category->id,
    'description' => 'required|min:200',
    'state' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in(['draft', 'published']),
    ]
]);
```

Comment: или `'state' => 'required|in:draft,published'`